# fglrx installation without success - gl_conf issue

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx

I followed the steps of [this guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide). I've installed the drivers without any problems with `sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb`.

The next step is **Generate a new `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file**, but I can't do this due to the following reason:

When I enter `sudo aticonfig --initial -f` the terminal show me this output:

```
sudo: aticonfig: command not found
```

---

This problem is caused by an error with the symbolics links into the fglrx directory. Look at [this section](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Aticonfig_not_found_after_installation_.26_.22module_does_not_exist.22_after_boot), where you can see **-how to fix it- but it doesn't work** for me. Why it doesn't? Because after I enter `sudo update-alternatives --auto gl_conf` the terminal show me this:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gl_conf.
```

What I have to do to fix this problem?  GC: **ATI RadeonHD 6670**

Comment: Did you Installed the dependencies to build the driver? it gives you command not found because the aticonfig tool is not Installed, you should get that fglrx is a broken package. Install the dependencies remove the driver and try again.

Comment: **First**, How can I install the dependencies? **Secondly**, How can I remove the driver?

Comment: In the guide you linked there are Instructions for both of your requests, just scroll down a bit. 3 and 6.

Comment: But there does not indicate anything about dependencies problems. What command should I use if `dpkg` doesn't work for me?

Comment: @UriHerrera Please, would you continue this in a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4783/installing-fglrx-drivers)?

Comment: use `sudo aticonfig --initial` instead of `sudo aticonfig --initial -f` and also check out [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers).

Comment: @Kaktarua When I type `aticonfig` I get this: `aticonfig: command not found`. Thanks for the link but is the same that the guide that I've posted.

Comment: try this, `sudo amdconfig --initial`. And post the output.

Comment: THE OUTPUT: `sudo: amdconfig: command not found`

Comment: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=18939.0, this maybe useful. :)

Comment: @Kaktarua Good source, after make the symbolic links the `aticonfig` is recognized. But when I enter `sudo aticonfig -f --initial --adapter=all` I get this: `aticonfig: No supported adapters detected`

Comment: Please remove and install it again. Lets see what happen.

Comment: Is ATI stupid by nature or forced by law?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have searched about this issu and understand that only fresh install of video driver can solve the problem. I think you messed up your driver. I have a fresh procedure to correctly install AMD driver but first refresh your repository cache with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now begin with installation procedure.

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

This will remove everything about AMD Driver. If any error occurred like `file not found` ignore it. Then, we need some dependent file to install this driver. Type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
```

Then download your appropiate driver from [here](http://www.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDHomePage.aspx).

Extract the `zip` file in your desktop and open a terminal

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-*.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric
```

It will create 3 `*.deb` files in your desktop.

Now use `sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb` to install driver in your system.

Now use `sudo aticonfig --initial -f` to create a new Xorg.conf file. Now reboot with

```
sudo reboot
```

After reboot check your working driver with `fglrxinfo`. This is  the right procedure to install AMD driver.

Comment: I do almost all your steps, then I did `reboot`. Now I can't enter to the system, the boot stop in `Cheking battery states.. [OK]` and I wait but nothing happens. What I should do if I can't enter to the system? See [this related questions](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=Boot+hangs+after+Checking+battery+state&submit=search), there is many similar cases.

Comment: I don't know....i have a one last suggestion...install ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Comment: The boot problem was solved by [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/187192/62483). You was right, now I installed my ATI card.