# How to solve unmet dependencies while installing fglrx on 12.04 64 bits?

Tags: 64-bit, dependencies, fglrx

Terminal output:

```
name@name:~$ sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
[sudo] password for name: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx-updates : Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please give a simple answer as I may not understand very complex ones.

Comment: try with the -f switch (stands for fix not force), you can also try aptitude, and if that doesn't work then we'll probably need more information.

Answer (score 2):

**Your answer**

If you have not installed `lib32gcc1` & `libc6-i386`, to fix the dependencies problem you should use `sudo gdebi fglrx*.deb` instead of `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`.

The GDebi is a tool that install `.deb` packages and solve *automatically* the independencies problems.

It is only one way of many to solve this. I recommend you use it because worked for me.

**Extra information**

I had some problems with the fglrx installation, see [My Question](https://askubuntu.com/q/186009/62483). It might be useful

Reference: [fglrx Installation Guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide)